# update top 10 records in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using the code below to try to update the `usage_flag` field. The code runs without error but the records are not updated.  Can anyone see anything that I'm doing wrong in my code below?

```
public void BookOut(Int32 _NoRecs, string _barcode)
{
   var queryProducts = (from p in e.Products
                        where p.barcode == _barcode
                        select p).Take(_NoRecs);

   foreach (var _p in queryProducts)
   {
      _p.usage_flag = "TEST";
   }
  e.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your query is returning records? This would suggest that either there are no items where `p.barcode == _barcode` or that `_NoRecs == 0`.

Comment: @MilenPavlov - How adding `ToList` will help? OP is enumerating over the result as you can see.

Comment: Did you try De-bugging?

Comment: _barcode is a string, no spaces, _NoRecs = 10 and queryProduct.count() = 10 also.  When I debug I can see the foreach loop executing fine 10 times.

Comment: I think you should first store a `List` of `Products`, and then apply `foreach` loop to update each item of the list.
`List<Products> p = from p in e.Products where p.barcode == _barcode select p).Take(_NoRecs).ToList();` and then `foreach(Product prdct in p) { prdct.use_flag = "TEST";`.

Comment: Have you opened a transaction that you forgot to commit? When your DataContext goes out of scope the transaction will be rolled back unless explicitly committed. Use SQL Server Profiler to see what is actually sent to the server

Comment: @Zeratops that's irrelevant. Whether you call `ToList` or enumerate with `foreach`, it's the *enumeration* that actually loads the data from the database, not where you store them. See the comment by RahulSingh

Comment: @brothers28 - do not have the option in intellisense for .SaveChanges()

Comment: SaveChanges is for Entitity Framework...

Comment: I would place a 'Debug.Assert(queryProducts.Any());' under the query and check if you even get results to be updated.

Comment: Problem sorted - the SQL field was a maximum of 3 characters as it should only accept 'IN' or 'OUT', I was trying to set it to 'TEST' for testing, doh!